# A mixin in my sass file is stopping my app from compiling?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

This is the error I get:

Properties are only allowed within rules, directives, mixin includes, or other properties.

It happens when I comment out @include label;

Can anyone assist?

Here's my code:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

@import 'settings/settings';  
@import 'foundation';
@include foundation-button;
@include foundation-dropdown;
@include label;

body {
  background-color: grey; 
}

div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

$button-palette: map-remove($foundation-palette, (
    primary,
    secondary
)) !default;
```

Comment: You are not including a rule within a property. What is including foundation-button modifying?

Comment: Please add the content of the used mixins. One of the mixins is writing only properties and not selectors.

Comment: A mixin can only be used in a selector.